# Failed to read descriptor from node connection

Tags: python, selenium

I am working in python with selenium.
I tried to make new file but still same problem.
[Here is an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg3vR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are entering the correct path where you have downloaded the chromedriver and **also put .exe** at end (chromedriver version should match your chrome version too)
Inside the **Chrome("your_path")** put your own path.
Check out my code it opens the google in chrome.

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "D:\Setup\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```